# Frontend connecting to middleware protected by keycloak-nodejs-connect (intended usage)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

Need to share some context and setup before asking my question, so please excuse the wall of text. =)

My app:

- `frontend` is a SPA served as a static resource from NGINX (`http://frontend`)
- `keycloak` server running on `http://keycloak`
- `middleware` is a NodeJS app that `frontend` communicates with as API endpoint (eg: `http://middleware`). Middleware is using keycloak-nodejs-connect (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect) to protect the API endpoint

setup code in middleware looks like this:

```
const session = require('express-session')
const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore()

app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}))

const keycloak = require('./auth/keycloak')
app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout'
}))
```

The setup in `auth/keycloak.js` is:

```
const keycloakConfig = {
  'realm': 'realmName',
  'auth-server-url': `http://keycloak/auth`,
  'ssl-required': 'external',
  'resource': 'clientName',
  'credentials': {
    'secret': 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-1a49c9dfbbef'
  }
}

module.exports = new Keycloak({store: memoryStore, responseType: 'code'}, keycloakConfig)
```

when a user clicks "/login" link from frontend, the `frontend` spawns a new tab and the new tab calls `http://middleware/login`. The motivation is for the existing state in UI to not be touched, all redirects etc happen in a new window. The code in `middleware` looks like this:

```
app.get('/login', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
  const keycloakTokens = JSON.parse(req.session['keycloak-token'])
  const userInfo = JSON.stringify(decodeToken(keycloakTokens))
  res.status(200).send(`<html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.opener.postMessage(${userInfo}, 'http://frontend')
            window.close()
        </script>
    </head></html>`)
})

const decodeToken = ({id_token}) => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(atob(id_token.split('.')[1]))
  return payload
}
```

So the idea is that after the OIDC dance, the middleware will respond asking the new tab to `postMessage` to the `opener` (parent) with the contents of the `id_token` JWT.

Assumption 1: the session in the cookie `connect.sid` is what the middleware uses to ensure the user is still authenticated. Is this assumption accurate?

there is a event listener in `frontend` that watches for the `postMessage` and saves the information sent (id_token) to localStorage.

Question 1: is this a correct way of doing login given the setup described above?

I think i'm definitely missing something because another protected route in `middleware` causes redirect to `keycloak` again telling me that middleware does not know the `frontend` is authenticated.

Question 2: how would logout work in this case? just clear the browser cookies?

I tried the example app (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/master/example) but that has a different architecture, the browser points to the middleware domain.

please let me know if you are looking for more code snippets or details. Happy to provide.

Comment: Are you using this middleware only to authenticate a client?